# Inscribed Angle Theorem to prove: "An angle inscribed in a semicircle is a right angle."

Tags: geometry, circles, proof-verification

I came across a question in my HW book:

> Prove that an angle inscribed in a semicircle is a right angle.

My proof was relatively simple:

*Proof:* As the measure of an inscribed angle is equal to half the measure of its intercepted arc, the inscribed angle is half the measure of its intercepted arc, that is a straight line.  As the arc's measure is $180^\circ$, the inscribed angle's measure is $180^\circ\cdot\frac{1}{2} = 90^\circ$.$\blacksquare$

When I checked the solution on the internet there were a whole bunch of other more complicated proofs.  Is mine valid?  If it is invalid, could someone tell me why?

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: If you already know the fact that the arc is 180, then yes.  Your proof is correct.  Based on geometry classes I have seen, this question is usually asked before the notion of degrees comes into play.  I would recommend trying it without the notion of angle measure.

Comment: @AJStas  I have already learnt about the measure of angles, so I suppose the proof is okay

Comment: As long as you are using information that you have already been taught, you should be fine.

Comment: @PaulFilch If I was a teacher assigning this as a homework problem, I would specifically forbid students from appealing to the inscribed angle theorem like this. Are you sure you are allowed to use that?

Comment: If you've already proven the Inscribed Angle Theorem (IAT), then your proof is valid. (You've simply identified the semi-circle property as an obvious *corollary* to the IAT.) Complicated proofs you've seen on the web are likely in the context of demonstrating the semi-circle property as a *prelude* to discussions of inscribed angles in general. Or perhaps they simply respond to the challenge of proving the result without resorting to the powerful IAT (which is a *little* like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly). IAT-less proofs don't have to be very complicated.

Comment: @PaulFilch As an enthusiast for history of math and science, I feel compelled to point out that the theorem you're asked to prove has a very special place in the history of mathematics. Known as [Thales' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem), it and its proof by Thales is to the best of our knowledge the first mathematical theorem ever proved. I think that makes his proof worth learning for its cultural significance alone.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Draw the radius from the center of the circle to the point that you think it has an angle of $90$ degrees and write down the angles:

$2(x+y)=180$

[image]

Comment: Filch wanted to ask whether his proof was correct or not, not the standard proof. You must edit your answer.

Comment: @Sawarnik this is not an answer. His way of thinking is correct. This hint helps him to see it.